# Inline Assembly - Display a register in decimal using printf?

Tags: c++, assembly, printf, inline-assembly

I just had a really quick question that I saw someone mention something about in another question, but I didn't want to necro-post on it.

I'm coding in inline assembly with c++, and need to display a register value in decimal. I was searching ways to do this, and saw someone mention "If you're using inline c, just call printf." But they didn't go much further into explanation on it than that.

Is it possible the call printf can be used to get a register value in decimal format without needing to write a conversion section of the code? And if so, how would that work? Say after some computations to a user entered integer, the value now lies in the AX register. Would I simply put call printf in the code after it? Or does it print values from the stack? Or is it maybe even possible to do something like:

```
AX printf
```

I apologize for my ignorance on this, our book does not cover inline assembly, and I'd like to avoid having to write a massive segment of code to convert if I can. Plus I can't really seem to find answers on how exactly printf works. Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You have tagged this "embedded", is it related to an *embedded system*, or did you mean "inline"?  In-line assembly syntax is not standardised as part of the C language, so you need to specify what compiler, and probably what processor - especially if this *is* about embedded systems.

Comment: My apologies, I did mean inline, I get the two terms mixed up a lot. I'll be sure to edit the title and tags really quick. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use inline assembler to copy your register to some variable, and then print that variable.

```
short registerValue;
__asm mov registerValue, ax;
printf("ax: %hd", registerValue);
```

The exact assembler invocation will depend on your compiler and syntax; the above likely won't work with a compiler other than cl.

If you want to actually call `printf` from assembler, you'll need to figure out it's calling convention and how that calling convention passes variadic function arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm using visual studio to code this, but I'll give this method a try and make it work with the syntax the best I can.

Comment: Just an update: The program is fully working now, and your suggested method of printf("%hd", value) actually worked perfectly in visual  studios. I actually kept the printf outside the assembly, and it was a lot easier then what I thought I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the compiler, there may be predefined pseudo-symbols which directly access the registers.  This was especially convenient with Turbo C and its descendants:

```
 _some_magic_function ();
 printf ("es:bx = %0x:%0x\n", _ES, _BX);
```